# Docker - Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to connect to mysql database from mysql image in docker using docker-compose with NestJS project .
but the connection gives me this Error :

> Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.

the connection options:

```
import * as mysql from 'mysql2/promise';

 const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5434,
    user: 'mysql',
    password: 'mysql',
    database: 'testDB',
    connectionLimit: parseInt(process.env.DB_CONNECTION_LIMIT || '20'),
  });
```

the docker-compose file :

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    container_name: drizzle-mysql-db
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 5434:5432

    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: mysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysql
      MYSQL_DATABASE: testDB
```

I'm stuck on the problem for a long time and I can't figure out why it won't connect!.

I am working on Postgres without problems with docker,but I need to work on MySQL currently. I hope I can find help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the port the default port for mysql is 3306 not 5432 .